# find and replace characters using regexp java string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to replace special characters between the following String when only when they are between two words, BEGIN and END . xxx to CCC and yyy to DDD, using Java regular expression or some way ? can you help

```
Raw string = "John Doe xxx Amazing man BEGIN reference xxx yes yyy indeed this is true xxx 
no yyy END , so this xxx does not change"
```

```
converted String = "John Doe xxx Amazing man BEGIN reference CCC yes DDD indeed this is true 
CCC no DDD END, so this xxx does not change"
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  Are you asking for [a Java method that can accept a regular expression as input to determine what to replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?  Or are you asking about  [how regular expressions work](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)?  Did you try anything?  Have code?  Error messages?  What is the specific breakage that is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your sample data displays `"xxx"` before `"yyy"`, there's no specification if `"xxx"` is before `"yyy"` or vice versa.  You just state, `"special characters between the following String when only when they are between two words, BEGIN and END"`.

I see having a `Map<String, String>` where the keys are your "special" strings and the values are the strings that'll replace the "special" strings.

Iterate through this map and provide the keys to this:

```
String.format("BEGIN.*?(%s).*?END", kvp.getKey())
```

In this example, it'll produce two regex patterns:

```
"BEGIN.*?(xxx).*?END"
"BEGIN.*?(yyy).*?END"
```

This will capture your "special" strings into capture group 1, which you'll provide to `String.replace()` like so:

```
raw = raw.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().replace(matcher.group(1), kvp.getValue()));
```

`matcher.group()` is the entire matching string `BEGIN ... END` and `matcher.group(1)` will either be `xxx` or `yyy`

Put this all together and you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> replacerMap = new HashMap() {{
        put("xxx", "CCC");
        put("yyy", "DDD");
    }};

    String raw = "John Doe xxx Amazing man BEGIN reference xxx yes yyy indeed this is true xxx no yyy END , so this xxx does not change";
    System.out.println("Before: ");
    System.out.println(raw);
    System.out.println();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> kvp : replacerMap.entrySet()) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(String.format("BEGIN.*?(%s).*?END", kvp.getKey())).matcher(raw);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            raw = raw.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().replace(matcher.group(1), kvp.getValue()));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("After: ");
    System.out.println(raw);
}
```

Results:

```
Before: 
John Doe xxx Amazing man BEGIN reference xxx yes yyy indeed this is true xxx no yyy END , so this xxx does not change

After: 
John Doe xxx Amazing man BEGIN reference CCC yes DDD indeed this is true CCC no DDD END , so this xxx does not change
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your pattern and matcher:

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("BEGIN" + "([ ]*+[0-9A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)*" + "xxx" + "([ ]*+[0-9A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)*" + "END");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(rawString);
```

Then you will call the find method on the matcher and every time it finds what you wanted will replace it with what you needed:

```
 while (m.find()) {
        rawString = rawString.replaceFirst(m.group(0),m.group(0).replaceAll("xxx","CCC"));
    }
```